# Execute commands when specific user and ip login to ssh

Tags: ssh, command

How can I execute a few commands when a specific user with a specific IP logs on via `ssh`?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in `~/.bash_profile` will be executed when a user logs in, so you can use that. For example with this code:

```
IP=`w | grep DarkGL | awk '{print $3}'`
if [ $IP = "192.168.10.10" ];
        then echo "Monkey"
fi
```

An alternative is using SSH forced commands, but you cannot configure this based on IP. This would mean a user can only run a specific binary and not even list files anywhere. We implemented this with git, so a user can only run the git binary.

If you can explain why you would want to do that, we can help things along.